# Do vegan instruments sound different from traditional instruments?

Tags: veganism

I love music. I play piano, guitar and I played violin, harmonica, flute... all in an amateur way.

I know that animal products have historically been a part of [almost all major instruments](http://www.peta.org/about-peta/faq/do-musical-instruments-utilize-animal-products/) around: violins use hair horse for their bows, some specific piano keys are made from ivory, drums use leather and so on, so [vegan instruments](http://www.peta.org/living/entertainment/animal-friendly-instruments/) is a great move towards a more respectful world.

Music experts value the sound of instruments and very small sound changes can make a significant difference.

**Are there any sound differences between vegan instruments and traditional instruments?**

Comment: This may need to be narrowed down. I know piano keys don't affect the sound (having played both), but that may not be the case for string instruments (e.g. a violin) -- or are you envisioning an answer that lists many possible instruments and the effect of veganizing?

Comment: @Erica exactly, I would love to know about violin and piano for example, but any other reference would be really appreciated!

Comment: This is a very interesting topic that I never realized was an issue, as a non-music-player.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve specifically? Different instruments use different animal-based products for various reasons; so a discussion about all instruments everywhere can only lead to random anecdotes without knowing if that information answers your question specifically.

Comment: @RobertCartaino sound is something you can actually measure, as you know it's related to wave vibration, and there are studies already measuring instruments sounds. Again, Im not asking for personal opinions or anecdotes, so a perfect valid answer would be "There's no study on it yet"

Comment: I don't think you want a simple *yes* or *no* answer, period. So for example, if I cited a study saying synthetic ivory keys make no difference while synthetic-hair violin bows are profound, I can go on for (literally) hundreds more answers with nuanced discussions about a wide variety of relative performance issues. So apart from "yes" or "no", this question isn't really "answerable" in the context of this site. ("Get answers to practical, detailed questions. Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced." — The [Stack Exchange Tour](http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/tour))

Comment: @RobertCartaino, there could be a great "long list" answer. I feel competent to answer the case for pianos and bowed string instruments, and maybe others can answer for drums. It could become a community wiki.

Comment: There's no need for it to be a community wiki imho - [What would be the benefit?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)